# Firebase packages not importing?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Is there a reason `FirebaseAuth`  within `FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;` is throwing an error? The error I am getting is:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.
```

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app1/theme/routes.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

In my pubsec.yaml, I have the dependency:   `firebase_auth: ^0.20.1`

Here are the other dependencies:

```
version: 1.0.0+1
 
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  form_validator: ">=0.1.1 <2.0.0"
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^3.1.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera: ^0.7.0+2
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  path: ^1.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  http: ^0.12.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
```

When I run flutter pub get, I just get a `Running "flutter pub get" in App1...`   and that's it. The process closes, but that is all I get

Comment: Have you run `flutter pub get` in your project?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad yes I have

Comment: `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad some of my other packages are not loading as well.. Camera, image picker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `dart pub get`, and it started working